# Location of Class Hash

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Just wondering where the class Hash is stored in my Laravel Application, which i use in my UserSeeder:

```
 $users = [
        [
            "username" => "dummy",
            "password" => Hash::make("testlogin"),
            "email"    => "testaddress@test.com"
        ],
```

I want to know a little bit about the laravel structure and so on. I found BCryptHasher Class in the vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate but thats not the class I use in my UserSeeder.
Can you give me a hint?

Also i found the hash.php in the laravel namespace [overview](http://v3.golaravel.com/api/source-class-Laravel.Hash.html#3-53). But i don't know where to find the file in my directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the entry point:**

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash.php
```

**This goes after:**

```
Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider.php
```

**Which instantiates** (this is where its methods like `make()` and `check()` are):

```
Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher.php
```

Comment: hey, thank you very much. Found it 1 sec ago , too. Was about to post my answer, but appreciate your effort to answer.
I found it throug the laravel/app/config/app.php aliases line 168

Comment: No problem.  Usually, iyou can start with app.php, then follow the namespaces from there.  Fuzzy file name searching works great in Sublime Text as well :)

Comment: please i need help in this point,i need to use Hash::make() in php file but it make a problem that "  include_once(app/config/app.php): failed to open stream"  ,Failed opening 'classes/Hash.php' for inclusion ,how can i use Hash class

Comment: @c-griffin I need your help for Hash class of Laravel. I have old project, developed in Cakephp 2.x version. I have thousands of existing customers on old online project. Cakephp 2.x version does not support latest php versions so I have re-write and re-developed in Lumen 8 version. Now the issue is that I do not want to say my customers that we have migrated/updated application version so please use forgot password to change your account password and at the time of forgot password I save their password with Lumen 8 Hash algo. So I need Lumen Hash algorithm file. Kindly suggest how to get it?

Comment: @c-griffin I will use this Lumen 8 Hash class at the time of login on old cakephp 2.x project to save their password in a new field in database and after 1-2 months when all the password will be saved in that new password field of Lumen 8 algo in database, I will use that users database to my newly developed Lumen 8 project then they will be able to access their account without changing their password. Kindly help to get Hash class which has Hash class functions eg. `Hash::make`, `Hash::check` etc. Thanks a lot..

Comment: @c-griffin `password_hash()` and `password_verify` php functions solved my problem. Thanks dear.